# SSIS - Incorrect syntax error every time I used SQL command from variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011

I am very new to SSIS. Every time I am getting syntax error when using "SQL command from variable" Data access mode in OLE DB editor. I created 2 variables..one with string type to store a SQL statement and another to store Int value. Please help me in guiding to correct the syntax

[image]

Comment: If your variable is an integer, it needs to be cast as a string in a statement like that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  And why is this tagged as CRM2011?

Answer (score 1):

1) For "SQL" variable, you need to specify an expression as below example:

```
"SELECT TOP " + (DT_STR, 10, 1252) @[User::NumberOfRecords] + " * FROM YourTable"
```

2) Then Use that "SQL" variable in the data source (SQL command from variable)